# HK2 Generic Subclass to NonGeneric Interface Binding

Tags: java, dependency-injection, hk2

I've 2 interfaces and 2 implementations like below.

- `KafkaConsumerExecutor` (Interface)
- `DefaultExecutor` (Implementation of 1)
- `ConsumerRecordsProcessor` (Interface)
- `LastOnlyRecordsProcessor` (Impl of 3.)

--

```
public interface KafkaConsumerExecutor {
        void start();
        void stop();
}

public class DefaultExecutor<MESSAGE_TYPE> implements KafkaConsumerExecutor {
    private final ConsumerRecordsProcessor<MESSAGE_TYPE> consumerRecordsProcessor;

@Override
public void start(){}
    //processStuff
}

@Override
public void stop(){}
    //kill
}

public interface ConsumerRecordsProcessor<MESSAGE_TYPE> {

    void process(Iterable<ConsumerRecord<String, MESSAGE_TYPE>> consumerRecords);
}
```

--

```
public class LastOnlyRecordsProcessor<MESSAGE_TYPE extends Serializable> implements ConsumerRecordsProcessor<MESSAGE_TYPE> {
    public void process(Iterable<ConsumerRecord<String, MESSAGE_TYPE>> consumerRecords){
     // process stuff.
    }
}
```

Finally, I have the class where I call start the executor.

```
@Inject
public KafkaListenerManagerImpl(ConsumerExecutor consumerExecutor) {
    this.consumerExecutor= consumerExecutor;
}
```

And my problem is, I cannot bind my generic implementation `DefaultExecutor<String>` to `ConsumerExecutor`

The ways I tried is;

1.

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<DefaultExecutor<String>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerExecutor>(){});
bind(LastOnlyRecordsProcessor.class).to(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerRecordsProcessor<Request>>() {});
```

This one fails with `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

2.

```
bind(DefaultExecutor.class).to(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerExecutor>() {});
bind(LastOnlyRecordsProcessor.class).to(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerRecordsProcessor<String>>() {});
```

This one looks better , but then It can't find the perspective however then I  don't have the binding for Processor.

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ConsumerRecordsProcessor<MESSAGE_TYPE>,parent=DefaultExecutor,qualifiers={},position=1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1237264838)
```

3. ```
     bind(DefaultExecutor.class).to(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerExecutor>() {});
     bind(new TypeLiteral<LastOnlyRecordsProcessor<String>>() {}).to(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerRecordsProcessor<String>>() {});
   ```

Again the same;

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ConsumerRecordsProcessor<MESSAGE_TYPE>,parent=DefaultExecutor,qualifiers={},position=1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,202064342)
```

Question in a nutshell is that,

1. I want to bind the DefaultExecutor to ConsumerExecutor.
2. LastRecordsOnlyProcessor to ConsumerRecordsProcessor

I don't have much hope, but do you guys see where am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This may be the issue.

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
        KafkaListenerManagerImpl kafkaListenerManager = injector.getInstance(KafkaListenerManagerImpl.class);
    }
}
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerExecutor<String>>(){}).to(DefaultExecutor.class);
        bind(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerRecordsProcessor<String>>(){}).to(LastOnlyRecordsProcessor.class);
    }
}
```

In this example, the `MyModule` class binds the `DefaultExecutor<String>` implementation to the `ConsumerExecutor` interface, and the `LastOnlyRecordsProcessor` implementation to the `ConsumerRecordsProcessor` interface.

Change;

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerExecutor<String>>(){}).to(DefaultExecutor.class);
```

to;

```
bind(ConsumerExecutor.class).to(DefaultExecutor.class);
```

and

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<ConsumerRecordsProcessor<String>>(){}).to(LastOnlyRecordsProcessor.class);
```

to;

```
bind(ConsumerRecordsProcessor.class).to(LastOnlyRecordsProcessor.class);
```

You have to make sure that you have imported the correct dependencies and classes.

Also, in `KafkaListenerManagerImpl` class, you should be injecting the `ConsumerExecutor<String>` instead of `ConsumerExecutor`:

```
@Inject
public KafkaListenerManagerImpl(ConsumerExecutor<String> consumerExecutor) {
    this.consumerExecutor= consumerExecutor;
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: I'm not using Guice. :(